# Android Dev - Android:versioncode won't update

Tags: java, android

Receiving the following message when uploading my latest APK:

> You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1.

I am setting the android:versionCode and android:versionName correctly (in /app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml):

> android:versionCode="2"
>
> android:versionName="1.1"

Also, I am using the same keystore that the project was initialized / originally built with

This is my 5th app and I've never encountered this issue before.

Is there some other place within a typical Android app project that could override the versionCode found in the AndroidManifest.xml file? Or maybe some kind of "de-linter" tool that'll help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path names suggest you're using Android Studio. Android Studio is using the Gradle build system. Possibly the `build.gradle` files specify version name/code that override whatever you set in manifest. So, to change it, edit your `build.gradle` file(s) and check for overridden `versionCode` / `versionName`.

Comment: This was exactly the issue. I removed the "versionCode" and "versionName" defaults in my build.gradle and everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your app. Then save all files and then build